# Robots.txt file not showing due to Web.config file

Tags: php, azure, web-config, robots.txt

I'm trying to access my robots.txt file with a direct link (https://www.example.com/robots.txt) however I keep getting a 404 error. I suspect it has something to do with my web.config file but I'm not entirely sure.

Here is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <!-- BEGIN rule TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
             <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
               <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
               <conditions>
                 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
             </rule>
             <!-- END rule TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
            <rule name="Rewrite to index.php">
                <match url="index.php|images|test.php" />
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

And my robots.txt file is simply

User-agent: *
Disallow:
Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml

I added the robots.txt file in the root directory of my web app. Any ideas for why it isn't showing up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue, but failed that the result is not as yours to get a `404` status code. Here is my steps as below.

1. I created a new WebApp and deployed some files include `robots.txt`, `index.php` (only one code `phpinfo();`) and `web.config` with the same content of yours. Then, I accessed `https://<my webapp name>.azurewebsites.net/robots.txt` to get the `200` response of `phpinfo()` as the figure below.

   [image]
2. I see the `robots.txt` url has been rewriten by the third rule below of yours to redirect to `index.php`.

   ```
   <rule name="Rewrite CI Index">
       <match url=".*" />
       <conditions>
           <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" />
   </rule>
   ```
3. So I changed the rule above to append `txt` to the `pattern` tail like below, then I review the `robots.txt` url which works.

   ```
   <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html|txt" negate="true" />
   ```

   [image]

Hope it helps.